# Gmail get api: Fetch messages of ALIAS email

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-api

I have an alias to an existing email. I am able to send & receive on alias email. Now, I'm only looking to get emails that were sent & received by alias using Gmail get api

 `email= xxx@gmail.com`

```
alias_email= xxx+agent@gmail.com
```

Request API: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/`<alias_email>`/messages

Response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Delegation denied for xxx@gmail.com"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Delegation denied for xxx@gmail.com"
 }
}
```

Does Gmail allow fetching of alias email data ?

Comment: Where did you get the reference for that URL request?

Comment: From hrere https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

Comment: Does it mention that you can use 'alias' in place of 'userId' ?

Comment: No, but is there a way i could pull it off?

Comment: dnt think so..i just follow the docs most of the times.

Comment: Alright, no issues, thanks for your time :)